# IP Adresses and Regular Expressions; Filter All But WAN IPs

Tags: regex, bash, regex-negation, ss

I suppose that `ss` is a good tool to extract connection information.  I would like a command that interrogates it with the most details, but returns only the lines containing a WAN-origin IP address.

For example, I would like the following output out of something based on `sudo ss -antu`:

```
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q            Local Address:Port                           Peer Address:Port              
tcp    ESTAB      0      0                   192.168.12.1:38932                        211.54.192.102:443                
tcp    SYN-RECV   0      0            ::ffff:192.168.12.1:80                       ::ffff:69.59.249.6:59937              
tcp    ESTAB      0      750          ::ffff:192.168.12.1:80                       ::ffff:69.59.249.6:59498
```

In short a list without:

- noise for my purposes
- private addresses `(127\.) | (10\.) | (172\.1[6-9]\.) | (172\.2[0-9]\.) | (172\.3[0-1]\.) | (192\.168\.)`

How does one go about this?  Regular expressions are not my *forte*.

Answer (score 0):

This is better solved with something that can do the bitwise math to determine if an ip address belongs to an ip block. Here's an example using the perl module, Net::CIDR. It'll print an ip address if it does not belong to one of the 3 RFC1918 private networks:

```
perl -mNet::CIDR -ne 'print unless Net::CIDR::cidrlookup($_, ("10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"))'
```